# How to export web project from CVS?

Tags: netbeans, cvs

I am using Netbeans to work on a CVS web project in Windows.

Is there a solution to export the project into a target directory without the metadata dotfiles created by Netbeans and "CVS" directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Examine "cvs export" command: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/cvs/export-project-from-cvs-repository.